# Copy constructor syntax error: myclass has no member mymember

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm trying to create a copy constructor for a Gregorian date to Julian date calculator.

```
myDate.cpp (minimal)

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "myDate.h"

        int month = 0, day = 0, year = 0;

        myDate::myDate()
        {
            month = 5; day = 11; year = 1959; // Default date
        }

        myDate::myDate(int M, int D, int Y)
        {
            month = M; day = D; year = Y;
        }

        myDate::myDate(const myDate& D)
        {
            month = D.month;
            day = D.day;
            year = D.year;
        }
```

I get the errors 'month' is not a member of 'myDate' (same for day and year) and class "myDate" has no member "month" (same for day and year). What is the correct syntax for creating a copy constructor? This is the syntax I have seen widely used. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the full header:

```
myDate.h

#ifndef MYDATE_H
#define MYDATE_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class myDate
{
    myDate();
    myDate(int M, int D, int Y);
    myDate(const myDate &D);
    string dayName();
    int getMonth();
    int getDay();
    int getYear();
    int Greg2Julian(int M, int D, int Y);
    void Julian2Greg(int JD, int& J, int& K, int& I);
    void display();
    void increaseDate(int N);
    void decreaseDate(int N);
    int daysBetween(myDate D);
    int dayOfYear();

};
#endif
```

and the full cpp:

```
myDate.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "myDate.h"
using namespace std;


        int month = 0, day = 0, year = 0;
        string months[12] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
        int dayCount[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
        string weekdays[7] = { "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday" };

        myDate::myDate()
        {
            month = 5, day = 11, year = 1959; // Default date
        }

        myDate::myDate(int M, int D, int Y)
        {
            int nM = M; int nD = D; int nY = Y;
            int JD = Greg2Julian(M, D, Y);
            Julian2Greg(JD, nM, nD, nY);
            if (nM == M && nD == D && nY == Y)
                month = M, day = D, year = Y;
            else
                month = 5, day = 11, year = 1959;
        }

        myDate::myDate(const myDate& D)
        {
            month = D.month;
            day = D.day;
            year = D.year;
        }

        int myDate::getMonth()
        {
            return month;
        }

        int myDate::getDay()
        {
            return day;
        }

        int myDate::getYear()
        {
            return year;
        }

        int myDate::Greg2Julian(int M, int D, int Y)
        {
            return D - 32075 + 1461 * (Y + 4800 + (M - 14) / 12) / 4 + 367 * (M - 2 - (M - 14) / 12 * 12) / 12 - 3 * ((Y + 4900 + (M - 14) / 12) / 100) / 4;
        }

        void myDate::Julian2Greg(int JD, int& J, int& K, int& I) //use reference variables
        {
            int L = JD + 68569;
            int N = 4 * L / 146097;
            L = L - (146097 * N + 3) / 4;
            I = 4000 * (L + 1) / 1461001;
            L = L - 1461 * I / 4 + 31;
            J = 80 * L / 2447;
            K = L - 2447 * J / 80;
            L = J / 11;
            J = J + 2 - 12 * L;
            I = 100 * (N - 49) + I + L;
        }

        void myDate::display()
        {
            cout << months[month-1] << " " << day << ", " << year;
        }

        void myDate::increaseDate(int N)
        {
            Julian2Greg(Greg2Julian(month, day, year) + N, month, day, year);
        }

        void myDate::decreaseDate(int N)
        {
            Julian2Greg(Greg2Julian(month, day, year) - N, month, day, year);
        }

        int myDate::daysBetween(myDate D)
        {
            return Greg2Julian(D.getMonth(), D.getDay(), D.getYear()) - Greg2Julian(month, day, year);
        }

        int myDate::dayOfYear()
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < month; i++)
            {
                if (month > i + 1)
                    sum += dayCount[i];
                else
                    sum += day;
            }
            return sum;
        }

        string myDate::dayName()
        {
            int dayNum = Greg2Julian(month, day, year) %7;
            return weekdays[dayNum];
        }
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of the `myDate` class in `myDate.h`. If the compiler says they are not members, then they really are not members.  Also, in your `myDate()` and `myDate(int, int, int)` constructors, the statements `month = ..., day = ..., year = ...;` should be separated by semicolons instead of commas: `{ month = ...; day = ...; year = ...; }`, like they are in your `myDate(const myDate&)` copy constructor.

Comment: Well they don't seem to be members, but global variables? You better create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Present your [MCVE] as instructed in the help centre.

Comment: And if all you have as members are those three variables you show as globals, then you don't need an explicit copy-constructor. The default compiler-generated copy-constructor will work fine.

Comment: Okay, well, it doesn't. There are no data members in that class..

Comment: Thank you for the code, but what you are doing is not really object-oriented programming... see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Since the variables are global, ***all*** instances of the `myDate` class will (in a way) share the same variables. If you change `month` for one object, it will be changed for *all* objects.

That's why you get errors for e.g. `D.month`, because there is no member `month` in the `myDate` class.

If you want those three to be actual members of the class, then you need to do something like

```
class myDate
{
    int month, day, year;

public:
    // The rest of the class and its member functions...
};
```

And then remove the global variables from the source file.

Lastly I suggest you get [a couple of good books to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), from the beginning.